# Is there an alternative for jvectormap

Tags: javascript, svg, maps, jvectormap

I'm working on a project using Vuejs (not using jQuery) and the project requires a map like jvectormap 
but as I said I'm not using jQuery, so is there any other library for creating maps without jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you can please specify which all things you have already searched for in VueJS in replacement of jVectorMap, that will help reduce the efforts by others.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find any alternative until I asked the question since I was searching for vector map not something like google map, I wanted a pure Javascript library.
I found this:
https://js.devexpress.com/Overview/ but it's paid and heavy.
and I found this 
https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/backgroundmap.html but I didn't like it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There're two good alternatives for me I'd recommend!

1) Using amcharts which is incredibly powerful alternative but you will need to use the whole library, about 150KB plus the map.
https://www.amcharts.com/

2) An alternative library for jvectormap I've created recently, you don't need jQuery anymore as a dependency to make it work!

Github repo: https://github.com/themustafaomar/jsvectormap
Demo: https://3iw9b.csb.app/
Code at https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-cdn-3iw9b

Comment: Does it includes the "multimap" feature?

Comment: Do you mean this drill-down feature in jvectormap ?
https://jvectormap.com/examples/drill-down/